# JSON Library - Jackson or Play Framework?

Tags: java, scala, json, playframework

Working on a Java and Scala code-base, there's a debate about whether to use Java's Jackson JSON or the Play Framework's JSON Library.

After reading the [Play JSON Docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson), as well as Chapter 9 (JSON) of [Play for Scala](http://www.manning.com/hilton/), I also ran through an example from [Mykong on Jackson](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/).

Based on looking at a few simple examples, Play's JSON Library seems like the superior choice due to, overall, its Functional Programming Approach:

- Providing compile-time safety when parsing JSON with Option/JsResult data types.
- As a result of the above, higher order functions (map/flatMap) are available and provide power and succintness
- As I understand, Jackson parses via the typical try/catch paradigm. Dealing with JSON errors at compile-time(Play) v. run-time(Jackson) is a no brainer

Bottom line - Play's JSON library uses a functional programming approach that results in code that is easier to reason about than the Jackson library.

Overall, the choice seems clear to me. Am I missing any pros/cons for either library?

Comment: Why the downvote? I believe that I've laid out a strong case for using Play's JSON Library, but am asking for more information on this debate.

Comment: +1. I'd suggest avoiding Jackson and spending some time with both Play JSON and [Argonaut](http://argonaut.io/). They're both really good libraries, and are similar in many ways, but the differences in emphasis can teach you a lot about library design in Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to note, first of all, that the Play ScalaJSON library *uses Jackson*. In effect, it is a *wrapper* around the parsing/formatting engine provided by Jackson, so it's a really good alternative. It provides a nice API around a very fast engine.

Now, the library I'd pick today for any JSON work would be [Argonaut](http://argonaut.io/). Argonaut is a true functional library from the ground up, and I like many of its decisions.

I don't really see any point in picking Jackson itself, unless you need the most speed you can get.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Is the `compile-time` distinction achieved with `Play JSON` by simply making use of `Option` (for parsing JSON) and `JsResult` (for validating JSON against a particular object)?

Comment: @KevinMeredith I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Could you speak more as to how JSON inception enables compile time safety?